# How to display a color channel in its own hue?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

When extracting a specific color channel from an image, the following code is used in EMGU CV:

```
EMGU.CV.UI.ImageBox originalImage;
EMGU.CV.UI.ImageBox bChannel;
...
Image<Bgra, Byte> image = new Image<Bgra, Byte>(filename);
originalImage = image;
bChannel = image[0]; // Index 0 is the blue channel (for BGRA).
```

Unfortunately, the resulting image assigned to `ImageBox bChannel` is in grayscale, *not* blue.  How can I display the image in its own hue (in this case, in blue)?

Eventually I would like to come up w/ a UI similar to the following:

[image]

PS: Additionally tagging this question w/ the "OpenCV" tag, based on the reasoning that EMGU is a wrapper for that library. :)

Comment: Probably cvSplit() is the method you are looking for: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/b4ed6c0c-dfa8-b94c-04a2-1fad23190417.htm

Comment: @marol I already have access to each separate channel via indexes of the original image (`image[0], image[1] and image[2]` for B, G, R, respectively).  The question is about displaying those images in hues as opposed to grayscale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really isn't my field, but nobody with a proper understanding has taken an interest, so unfortunately you're stuck with me for now.

There's more than one "right" way to do this. Your first try, setting the "off hue" channels to zero, is simple and straightforward and unquestionably has the effect of isolating the color channels, but it's not at all the same algorithm as the desert arch example. The visual effect is very different.

For simplicity, I'm only going to discuss "isolating" the red channel. The same principles apply to the other two, roughly (more on that later).

What the desert arch example is doing is, roughly, preserving the overall luminosity: A white pixel in the original image ends up as a white pixel in the result; a black pixel does likewise. A pixel with R=128 should be red (and so on, for a smooth curve).

*How* red?

For our purposes here, when we say a color is "red", we mean the G and B channels are the same, and that value is less than R. Maybe a little less, maybe a lot less. As we approach black at the low end the values converge toward zero, and as we approach white at the high end, the values converge toward 255. In the middle, they diverge a fair amount (if there's a canonically *correct* amount, I hope somebody who knows more than I comes along at some point). The more they diverge, the more saturated your red will be. The curve looks something like this highly sophisticated technical data visualization here:

[image: Highly sophisticated technical data visualization]

That lower curve describes a function f(R), where f(0)=0, f(255)=255, and f(128) is equal to some number less than 128. If you want to color to be noticeably red, it'd better be quite a lot less.

I take my shoes off when I count past ten, so I emailed the above image to a friend who keeps his on. He suggested the following "power law" formula:

```
x = 1.5
f(R) = 255 * Math.Pow(R/255, x);
```

...where `x` is an exponent. If `x = 1.0`, then `f(R)=R`, which isn't much use. Values of x from `1.5` to `2.5` are working for me. You can tune `x` to zero in on the right visual effect.

So if you're isolating R,

```
G = B = f(R)
```

If you're isolating G,

```
R = B = f(G)
```

If you're isolating B,

```
R = G = f(B)
```

However, it turns out that in practice the three channels are not perfectly symmetrical. Crudely put, #00ff00 is brighter than #ff0000, which is brighter than #0000ff. And from fiddling around with the above function, I think the algorithm that produced your example may be taking that into account.

If I were you, I'd tune x separately depending on which channel you're "isolating", to best approximate the original image. In some quick fiddling around, I ended up with using x=2.0 for R, x=2.5 for G, and x=1.6 for B.

I'm pretty sure it's still the wrong curve, but it's the right general idea. Depending on how close you have to nail this thing, you might want to Google "power law" and try different curve functions.

Comment: Ed, thanks so much for your answer and for the guidance.  I have tried the different pow values and updated my answer.  The individually tuned pow values do look best.  Can't think of a better answer, and unfortunately, I can only upvote once.

Comment: My pleasure -- it's one of those questions you get personally invested in.

Comment: You had a different SO name before - what was it? Ed ...?

Answer (score 0):

After posting my question, I realized that I can isolate a channel by setting all other channel values to 0 (black).  Here's my code:

```
Image<Bgra, Byte> img = new Image<Bgra, Byte>(filename);
Image<Bgra, Byte> blue = img.Copy();
Image<Bgra, Byte> green = img.Copy();
Image<Bgra, Byte> red = img.Copy();
Bgra tmp;
double saveGreen;
double saveRed;

for (int ii = 0; ii < img.Height; ii++)
{
    for (int jj = 0; jj < img.Width; jj++)
    {
        tmp = img[ii,jj];
        saveGreen = tmp.Green;
        saveRed = tmp.Red;

        // Blue
        tmp.Green = 0;
        tmp.Red = 0;
        blue[ii,jj] = tmp;

        // Green
        tmp.Green = saveGreen;
        tmp.Blue = 0;
        green[ii, jj] = tmp;

        // Red
        tmp.Red = saveRed;
        tmp.Green = 0;
        red[ii,jj] = tmp;
    }
}

imageBox1.Image = img;
imageBox2.Image = blue;
imageBox3.Image = green;
imageBox4.Image = red;
```

The resulting UI is as follows:

[image]

Please post answer or comment if you think the resulting channel images do not look right or if you can think of a faster approach without having to visit each pixel.

**EDIT #1 FOLLOWING COMMENT BY ED PLUNKETT:**

I implemented the following code for setting the channel colors:

```
Bgra tmp;
Bgra save;

for (int ii = 0; ii < img.Height; ii++)
{
    for (int jj = 0; jj < img.Width; jj++)
    {
        tmp = img[ii,jj];
        save = tmp;

        // Red channel.

        if (tmp.Red == 255)
        {
            tmp.Blue = tmp.Green = 255;
        }
        else
            if (tmp.Red == 0)
            {
                tmp.Blue = tmp.Green = 0;
            }
            else
                if (tmp.Red < 128)
                {
                    tmp.Blue = tmp.Green = tmp.Red / 2;
                }

        red[ii, jj] = tmp;

        // Green channel.

        tmp = save;

        if (tmp.Green == 255)
        {
            tmp.Blue = tmp.Red = 255;
        }
        else
            if (tmp.Green == 0)
            {
                tmp.Blue = tmp.Red = 0;
            }
            else
                if (tmp.Green < 128)
                {
                    tmp.Blue = tmp.Red = tmp.Green / 2;
                }

        green[ii, jj] = tmp;

        // Blue channel.

        tmp = save;

        if (tmp.Blue == 255)
        {
            tmp.Green = tmp.Red = 255;
        }
        else
            if (tmp.Blue == 0)
            {
                tmp.Green = tmp.Red = 0;
            }
            else
                if (tmp.Blue < 128)
                {
                    tmp.Green = tmp.Red = tmp.Blue / 2;
                }

        blue[ii, jj] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Also, I used the desert image and moved the channels around so the order matches the RGB order in the sample image.  Here's the output:

[image]

It's not quite the same (the red channel is too much like the original image) but overall looks more like the split used in the sample desert picture.

**EDIT #2 FOLLOWING ANSWER BY ED PLUNKETT:**

Here's the output for pow = 1.5:

[image]

Output for pow = 2.0:

[image]

Output for pow = 2.5:

[image]

Output for pow = 2.0 for Red, 2.5 for Green, and 1.6 for Blue, respectively:

[image]

Comment: What you've got is legitimate and if it's what you want, you're fine. But it's not the method that was used in the desert example images. For that: Say you're doing the "red channel": R=0 should yield a black pixel and R=255 should yield a white pixel. So setting G and B to zero is no good if R=255. But G and B should be the same so they don't affect hue. Therefore, G and B will be some function f(R) where f(0)=0, f(255)=255, and f(128) < 128 (you don't want your red turning to cyan).

Comment: @EdPlunkett Ed, thank you so much.  I edited my answer above.  Could you please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?  I now understand that the process is not a simple setting of the other channels to 0, but is more involved.  You say "you don't want your red turning to cyan" -- that comment leads me to assume that there is an art to this process, and would appreciate it if you could give me some resources to study.  Thank you again.